# View details of item in many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

guys. What I need is just to view details about my Article in my View ArticleDetail. Everything works except tags. I have many-to-many relationship between Articles and Tags:

```
     public class Article
{        
    public int Id {get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] HeroImage { get; set; }        
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ArticleTag> ArticlesTags { get; set; }
    public Article()
    {
        ArticlesTags = new List<ArticleTag>();
    }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ArticleTag> ArticlesTags { get; set; }

    public Tag()
    {
        ArticlesTags = new List<ArticleTag>();
    }
}

public class ArticleTag
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

My ArticleDetail is:

```
    @model MyBlog.Models.Article
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Article Detail";
}
<div>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt></dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt></dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
        </dd>

        <dt></dt>
        <dd>
            @foreach (var t in Model.ArticlesTags)
            {@t.Tag.Name}  //?? is it right?

        </dd>

        <dt></dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Category)
        </dd>
    </dl>   
</div>
```

But how should I change my HomeController (now i have only one for view details about article without any tags)?

```
  [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("ArticleDetail")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ArticleDetail(int? id)
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            Article article = await db.Articles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
            if (article != null)
                return View(article);
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to ask EF to get the `ArticleTags` along with the `Article`.

Luckily you can achieve that using the navigation properties you have in your entity model to load the related data you want using `Include` and `ThenInclude` methods to load the `ArticleTags` and then load the `Tags` inside the article tags.

E.g:

```cs
Article article = await db.Articles.Include(a => a.ArticlesTags).ThenInclude(at => at.Tag).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
```

You can read about [Loading Related Data here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)